# How do I import modules in Coq?

Tags: import, module, coq

I'm having trouble importing definitions from modules in Coq. I'm new to Coq, but couldn't solve the problem using the language's reference manual or online tutorial. I have a module that defines a signature and axioms for finite sets, which I intend to implement in another module. There's more to it, but it looks something like this (for reference, I'm closely following Filliatre's paper on finite automata):

```
Module FinSet.    
...
Parameter fset     : Set -> Set.
Parameter member   : forall A : Set, A -> finset A -> Prop.
Parameter emptyset : forall A : Set, fset A.
Parameter union    : forall A : Set, fset A -> fset A -> fset A.
...
Axiom axiom_emptyset :
  forall A : Set, forall a : A, ~ (member a (emptyset A)).
Axiom axiom_union    :
  forall A : Set, forall a b : fset A, forall x : A, i
    member x (union a b) <-> (member x a) \/ (member x b).
...
End FinSet.
```

I compile the module using `coqc` and attempt to load it into another module, say `FinSetList` or `FinSetRBT`, with the command `Require Import FinSet`. When I attempt to import the module, Coq (via Proof General) issues the warning:

```
Warning: trying to mask the absolute name "FinSet"!
```

Furthermore, I can't see anything defined in `FinSet`. How do I import the definitions (in this case, axioms) from one module into another? I essentially followed the steps outlined in Pierce's "Software Foundations" lectures. However, they aren't working for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your confusion arises from the fact that in Coq, "module" can mean two different things - a source file (Foo.v) and a module within a source file (`Module Bar.`) Try naming your source file differently from your module in that source file. Then use `Require Import` to import one source file into another (so, specify the name of the source file, not the name of the module in the source file).

Also, I am not very familiar with `Module`s and `Module Type`s in Coq, but don't you need to have `Module Type` there, not `Module`?

Comment: Yes, this seems to be right. I apparently wasn't importing modules correctly.

Comment: The source file has to be compiled with `coqc name_of_the_source.v` before being imported with `Require Import name_of_the_source`. You can also, if different paths are involved, use `Add LoadPath "../mypath/"` at the beginning of your `.v` file.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding to your `.emacs` file some explicit include paths:

```
 '(coq-prog-args (quote ("-I" "/home/tommd/path/to/some/stuff/lib" "-I" "/home/tommd/path/to/more/stuff/common")))
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this. The combination of `Add LoadPath "/home/pordan30/test"` in a `.v` file and `'(coq-prog-args (quote ("-I" "/home/pordan30/test")))` in my `.emacs` file results in the same problem when importing compiled modules in `~/test` (i.e., in that `.v` file in which the loadpath is added). Thanks for offering some help, though.