# Importing a Module in Coq

Tags: import, coq, coqide

I have the following folder structure:

```
- BaseDefs.v
- UsingBaseDefs.v
```

Here, `BaseDefs.v` contains definitions that I want to use in `UsingBaseDefs.v`. I tried to use the `coqc BaseDefs.v` command from the terminal and then I tried to import the module inside of `UsingBaseDefs.v` using:

```
Require Import BaseDefs.
```

This gives me the error

> Cannot find a physical path bound to logical path BaseDefs

I am working inside of CoqIDE and from another thread ([How do I import modules in Coq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7904535/how-do-i-import-modules-in-coq)) it seems as if this should work. How do I resolve this error and make the Import available ?

Edit: If I print the LoadPath using the `Print LoadPath` command inside of `UsingBaseDefs.v` I can see that BaseDefs is not listed here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: you are probably missing a `_CoqProject` file.

The Coq build system use this `_CoqProject` file (see [the reference manual](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/practical-tools/utilities.html#building-a-project-with-coqproject-overview)) to know what files are part of a multi-file project when building. Accordingly, IDEs use this system as well to do the mapping between the logical path (the one used in the `Require Import` command) and the system directory structure. Without such a file, CoqIDE does not know what `BaseDefs` refers to.

In your case, the `_CoqProject` probably needs to be something like

```
-R . MyProject

BaseDefs.v
UsingBaseDefs.v
```

to be located in the same folder as your two files. The first line tells Coq to map the `.` folder to the logical name `MyProject`. The next two lines makes it aware of the two files you have in that project. You can find a more complete typical template for a Coq project [here](https://github.com/palmskog/coq-program-verification-template), with e.g. a `MakeFile`.

Comment: It seems as if I made a Rookie mistake and got confused with the loading of the files. I forgot to reload the files using CoqIDE after compiling. Once I have done that I could Import them. However, a _CoqProject file will make my life easier!

Answer (score 0):

While a solution using a `_CoqProject` file is recommended following the [Coq Developer Page on Building Projects](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/practical-tools/utilities.html), there is another way to make imports available by hand:

If I compile the source file `BaseDefs.v` using the command `coqc BaseDefs.v` from the terminal, I get a new `BaseDefs.vo` file. Then, when I open `UsingBaseDefs.v` **after the compilation process** from the same directory in a **new** CoqIDE environment, it will load anything from that file in the LoadPath and the import is available using:

`Require Import BaseDefs.`